# How to set tab size in Red Hat VS Code XML formatter

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, format, redhat

I'm using [Red Hat Extension](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml) for VS Code to format XML. It formats with 4 spaces per indent.

```
<element>
    <subelement/>
</element>
```

How do I configure it to use 2 spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had `Tab Size` set to 2.

Turning off `Detect Indentation` changed the formatted XML to 2 spaces per indent.

See *Preferences → Settings*

[image]

Comment: Where do you do that?